# line simplification algorithm: Visvalingam vs Douglas-Peucker

Tags: algorithm, polygon, computational-geometry, simplification

I am trying to implement a *line simplification algorithm*. The main 2 algorithms I found are:

- [Ramer-Douglas-Peucker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramer%E2%80%93Douglas%E2%80%93Peucker_algorithm)
- [Visvalingam-Whyat](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/simplify)

Currently I am running a few simulations of them on Matlab in order to determine which answers my needs better.

The main goal for the algorithm is to simlipfy polygons in a map.
My Input is a polygon\polyline and a threshold for mistake- epsilon.

I need the simplified polygon to be as close as possible to the original, 
and I do not have a requirment for number of points to keep.

I am having difficulties in comparing the two algorithms because:
epsilon for RDP is a distance while epsilon for VW is an area. 
I need help understanding how to compare between the two algorithms.
which can give me less points to keep within the threshold?

Comment: There is some direct comparison attempted in [this study](https://www.fig.net/resources/proceedings/2006/baden_2006_comm6/PDF/MOD2/Blaszczak.pdf)
If you port Vishwalingam algo to opencv you can directly compare them with its existing approxPolyDP library results.

Answer (score 21):

> I need the simlified polygon to be as close as possible to the
>   original, and I do not have a requirment for number of points to keep.

DP method will give you better perceptible fit with lesser number of points - as its control parameter i.e the distance tolerance is captured by your requirement 'as close as possible'.

Having said that, the scale of the overall polygon or point-cloud relative to the pixel dimensions will have a bigger impact for smaller images. The exercise below can give you a 'feel' for how the two algorithms perform.

Here are some comparisons I ran between Visvalingam-Whyatt and Ramer-Douglas-Peucker for a few contours contained in what is around 100x100 bitmap originally. The images are screenshots of a ~ 10x zoom on the contours.

(you might want to download the images to appreciate the differences in performance)

**Visvalingam-Whyatt method results** : courtesy  [Zach's implementation on github](https://github.com/ofZach/Visvalingam-Whyatt) ported to opencv data types. 
[image: VSV simplification - with 0.1(white), 0.5(red), 1(magenta), 2(cyan) distance tolerances]

VSV simplification - with 0.55(white), 0.4(red), 0.25(magenta), 0.15(cyan) percentage tolerances

VSV - point reductions t : % tolerance . this directly determines n = t*orig/100. n is the final number of points

```
orig 88: [n=47 for t=0.55], [n=34 for t=0.4], [n=20 for t=0.25], [n=12 for t=0.15]
orig 133: [n=72 for t=0.55], [n=52 for t=0.4], [n=32 for t=0.25], [n=18 for t=0.15]
orig 118: [n=63 for t=0.55], [n=46 for t=0.4], [n=28 for t=0.25], [n=16 for t=0.15]
orig 107: [n=57 for t=0.55], [n=41 for t=0.4], [n=25 for t=0.25], [n=15 for t=0.15]
orig 107: [n=57 for t=0.55], [n=41 for t=0.4], [n=25 for t=0.25], [n=15 for t=0.15]
orig 268: [n=146 for t=0.55], [n=106 for t=0.4], [n=65 for t=0.25], [n=39 for t=0.15]
orig 158: [n=85 for t=0.55], [n=62 for t=0.4], [n=38 for t=0.25], [n=22 for t=0.15]
orig 158: [n=85 for t=0.55], [n=62 for t=0.4], [n=38 for t=0.25], [n=22 for t=0.15]
orig 109: [n=58 for t=0.55], [n=42 for t=0.4], [n=26 for t=0.25], [n=15 for t=0.15]
orig 192: [n=104 for t=0.55], [n=75 for t=0.4], [n=46 for t=0.25], [n=27 for t=0.15]
orig 132: [n=71 for t=0.55], [n=51 for t=0.4], [n=31 for t=0.25], [n=18 for t=0.15]
orig 89: [n=47 for t=0.55], [n=34 for t=0.4], [n=21 for t=0.25], [n=12 for t=0.15]
orig 110: [n=59 for t=0.55], [n=42 for t=0.4], [n=26 for t=0.25], [n=15 for t=0.15]
orig 40: [n=20 for t=0.55], [n=14 for t=0.4], [n=8 for t=0.25], [n=4 for t=0.15]
```

---

**DP method results** using openCV approxPolyDP

[image: DP simplification - with 0.1(white), 0.5(red), 1(magenta), 2(cyan) distance tolerances]

Douglas-Peucker - point reductions t : pixel distance tolerance => no direct correlation to n - the final number of points

```
orig 88: [n=33 for t=0.1], [n=29 for t=0.5], [n=8 for t=1], [n=6 for t=2]
orig 133: [n=57 for t=0.1], [n=45 for t=0.5], [n=12 for t=1], [n=7 for t=2]
orig 118: [n=50 for t=0.1], [n=40 for t=0.5], [n=15 for t=1], [n=8 for t=2]
orig 107: [n=47 for t=0.1], [n=35 for t=0.5], [n=11 for t=1], [n=6 for t=2]
orig 107: [n=30 for t=0.1], [n=24 for t=0.5], [n=8 for t=1], [n=6 for t=2]
orig 268: [n=126 for t=0.1], [n=110 for t=0.5], [n=32 for t=1], [n=23 for t=2]
orig 158: [n=80 for t=0.1], [n=62 for t=0.5], [n=17 for t=1], [n=11 for t=2]
orig 158: [n=66 for t=0.1], [n=52 for t=0.5], [n=16 for t=1], [n=9 for t=2]
orig 109: [n=50 for t=0.1], [n=38 for t=0.5], [n=12 for t=1], [n=9 for t=2]
orig 192: [n=74 for t=0.1], [n=64 for t=0.5], [n=18 for t=1], [n=15 for t=2]
orig 132: [n=58 for t=0.1], [n=45 for t=0.5], [n=14 for t=1], [n=11 for t=2]
orig 89: [n=37 for t=0.1], [n=31 for t=0.5], [n=7 for t=1], [n=6 for t=2]
orig 110: [n=42 for t=0.1], [n=36 for t=0.5], [n=9 for t=1], [n=7 for t=2]
orig 40: [n=18 for t=0.1], [n=15 for t=0.5], [n=9 for t=1], [n=3 for t=2]
```

---

**Summary :**

- Both the methods degrade gracefully.
- VSV lets you specify the number of approximated points (in this implementation)
- VSV in this implementation lets you pick multiple approximate polygons in one shot.
- VSV retains a lot of pixel level convexity inflections even for large curvature sections - this could be undesirable in some cases.
- DP follows the convexities better and smooths out inflections more but by sacrificing 'closeness'.
- As a result, DP gives lesser number of points for the same percieved tolerance - which is anyway hard to compare between the two methods
- DP give a better feel for tolerance as its a linear distance specification.

For my application, I prefer the control offered by VWV in this implementation over the possible efficiency of DP method.

But overall I feel openCVs's DP implementation gives a smoother perception.

Though my conclusions of VSV performance are based on Zach's implementation alone, I doubt if other implementations will give characteristically different polygon subsets.

[UPDATE1] Here is the comparison for a worst case scenario. DP is visually more acceptable.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Sith for your detailed reply. I've very recently written my own line simplification code - https://github.com/AngusJohnson/Clipper2/issues/378 - that better handles polygons (as well polylines), which the DP algorithm doesn't handle well So what I would find really helpful would be a link to the coordinates of the unsimplified lines in your images. Cheers.

Comment: @AngusJohnson Sorry those shapes coods were generated by some binary image segmentation algorithms I was playing with way back. I was able to locate the source image though - https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ze6GkrKY4JMjddX8PkuUh8zNJkSMakjT/view?usp=share_link. This image is just random scribbles on MS paint or some such program just for illustration purpose.